# reading and writing file using autoresetevent in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, autoresetevent, event-wait-handle

I have written a simple program of thread synchronization. But when I run this program I get an error "The process cannot access the file 'D:\Vivek.txt' because it is being used by another process." Why I am getting this error.

```
class Program
{
    const string Filepath = "D:\\Vivek.txt";
    static AutoResetEvent writerwaithandle= new AutoResetEvent(true);// Signaled state
    static AutoResetEvent readerwaithandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    static void Main()
    {

        if (File.Exists(Filepath))
        {
            File.Delete(Filepath);                                          
        }

        File.CreateText(Filepath);
        CreateWriterThread();
        CreateReaderThread();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void CreateWriterThread()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10;i++ )
        {

            var thread = new Thread(WriteFile);
            thread.Name = "Writer " + i;
            thread.Start();
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }

    }

    private static void CreateReaderThread()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(ReadFile);
            thread.Name = "Reader " + i;
            thread.Start();
        }
    }

    private static void WriteFile()
    {
        writerwaithandle.WaitOne();

        var stream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append);
        var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
        streamwriter.WriteLine("written by"+Thread.CurrentThread.Name+DateTime.Now));
        streamwriter.Flush();
        streamwriter.Close();

        readerwaithandle.Set();
    }

    private static void ReadFile()
    {
        readerwaithandle.WaitOne();
        if (File.Exists(Filepath))
        {
            var stream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open);
            var streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
            var text = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
            streamreader.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Read by thread {0} \n",Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
        writerwaithandle.Set();
    }
}
```

when I replace the code from

```
if (File.Exists(Filepath))
{
  File.Delete(Filepath);                                          
}
  File.CreateText(Filepath);
```

to

```
if (!File.Exists(Filepath))
{
  File.CreateText(Filepath);
}
```

the program shows the same error for first time. after that it never gives any error.
please anyone tell me the bug area, reason and what should be the best solution.

Comment: maybe your file is open in some other software like notepad?
close it and try again.

Comment: `File.CreateText(Filepath);` leaves the file open. You need to close it using the return value: `File.CreateText(Filepath).Dispose();`

Comment: I am agree with you Maththew. File.CreateText(filepath) leaves the file open, so updating the code if (File.Exists(Filepath)) { File.Delete(Filepath); } var stream = File.CreateText(Filepath); stream.Close(); gives us the required result. Thanks to you for participating.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `FileStream` always use it with `using` like

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open))
{
   Your code...
}
```

This ensures that the stream gets disposed properly.

You can also use the `StreamReader` along with `using`

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        Your code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be vigilant, [look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.createtext.aspx) at the documentation of `File.CreateText`

> Creates or opens a file for writing UTF-8 encoded text.
>
> Return Value Type: System.IO.StreamWriter A StreamWriter that writes
>
> to the specified file using UTF-8 encoding

It means that there is no need to create a new FileStream because FileStream is already created and returned when you use `File.CreateText`. You should only use that created FileStream in your code.

Here is the fixed version of your code:

```
 class Program
    {
        const string Filepath = "D:\\Vivek.txt";
        static AutoResetEvent writerwaithandle = new AutoResetEvent(true);// Signaled state
        static AutoResetEvent readerwaithandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        static void Main()
        {

            if (File.Exists(Filepath))
            {
                File.Delete(Filepath);
            }

            //File.CreateText(Filepath);
            CreateWriterThread();
            CreateReaderThread();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void CreateWriterThread()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {

                var thread = new Thread(WriteFile);
                thread.Name = "Writer " + i;
                thread.Start();
                Thread.Sleep(250);
            }

        }

        private static void CreateReaderThread()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                var thread = new Thread(ReadFile);
                thread.Name = "Reader " + i;
                thread.Start();
            }
        }

        private static void WriteFile()
        {
            writerwaithandle.WaitOne();


            var streamwriter = File.CreateText(Filepath);

            //var stream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Append);
            //var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(stream);
            streamwriter.WriteLine("written by" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + DateTime.Now);
            streamwriter.Flush();
            streamwriter.Close();

            readerwaithandle.Set();
        }

        private static void ReadFile()
        {
            readerwaithandle.WaitOne();
            if (File.Exists(Filepath))
            {
                var stream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open);
                var streamreader = new StreamReader(stream);
                var text = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                streamreader.Close();
                Console.WriteLine("Read by thread {0} \n", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
                Console.WriteLine(text);
            }
            writerwaithandle.Set();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am agree with Maththew watson. File.Create(filepath) leaves the file open, so updating the code

    if (File.Exists(Filepath))
            {
               File.Delete(Filepath);
            }
            var stream = File.CreateText(Filepath);
            stream.Close();

gives us the required result
Thanks to all for participating.